# Add loyalty card to Google Pay via Google Play Services API

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-pay

I have problem with adding loyalty card to google pay app using google play services api. I have got account verficication after google pay request, but I'm receiving 400 in logs.

Can't find what's wrong...

Code below has been written following this guides:

https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay#from-native-android-app

https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/overview/basics/typical-api-flow

Attached code (**Take a look on comments, it's important**)

```
// is 9999999
val userId : String = usr.idUser.toString()
// value is "John Snow"
val fullname : String = usr.fullname
// ISSUER_ID - is numeric value from console

val wob = LoyaltyWalletObject.newBuilder()
//    the class id has similar name. All characters has been replaced with 'x' character
    .setClassId("$ISSUER_ID.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx")
//    similar to comment from method setClassId
    .setId("$ISSUER_ID.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.$userId")
    .setState(WalletObjectsConstants.State.ACTIVE)
//   id of user in app
    .setAccountId(userId)
//   name of user in app
    .setAccountName(fullname)
//    from console - "Issuer" = Loyalty
    .setIssuerName("Loyalty")
//    from console - "Program Name" = Loyalty card
    .setProgramName("Loyalty card")
//    barcode type from docs  
    .setBarcodeType("code128")
//   card 16 digits card number
    .setBarcodeValue("1234567890123456")
//   formatter card number
    .setBarcodeAlternateText("1234 5678 9012 3456")
//   url on web resources
    .addLinksModuleDataUris(uris)
    .build()

val request = CreateWalletObjectsRequest.newBuilder()
    .setLoyaltyWalletObject(wob)
    .build()

val opts = Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
    .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
    .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
    .build()

val client = Wallet.getWalletObjectsClient(activity, opts)
val task = client.createWalletObjects(request)
AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(task,activity,UIRequestCode.RC_GPAY)
```

The log:

```
E: [13290] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://wallet.google.com/payments/apis/instantbuy/android/v1/createWalletObjects
E: Exception sending Volley request
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.ClientError
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):4)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.get(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):1)
    at atew.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):29)
    at atew.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):25)
    at atyd.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):8)
    at atxx.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):16)
    at atof.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):4)
    at atxw.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):4)
    at atyg.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):2)
    at atxq.a(Unknown Source:2)
    at atxu.a(Unknown Source:19)
    at xrb.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):3)
    at cpb.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):4)
    at atxq.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):1)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
    at dry.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):3)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
 Caused by: com.android.volley.ClientError
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):49)
    at qni.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):13)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):6)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@14574021@14.5.74 (040408-219897028):2)
E: Unknown ServerResponse type=1
```

Github issue: https://github.com/google-pay/s2gp-quickstart-android/issues/4   (sample code, developer Guide for passes APIs not yet updated by Google passes API team)

Comment: got any solution? it's a bug or whitelisting problem? please update

Comment: .setCreateMode(SHOW_SAVE_PROMPT) is needed ?

Comment: No, our team didn't get any solution for this. Out discussion is in progress with google.

Comment: @LOG_TAG - unfortunately .setCreateMode(SHOW_SAVE_PROMPT) doesn't work for testing for us

Comment: same here! let me know if you get solution from google team , I will also update you on the progress! please comment here also https://github.com/google-pay/s2gp-quickstart-android/issues/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your app needs to be whitelisted by the Google Pay team.
>   Yes, is very important, but...

I sent to Google Pay team my release SHA1 Fingerprint (https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/native-android-sdk). After that, when install app directly from apk file, all start work great (when click on "Add To GPay" -> loyalty card add to Google Pay)!

But continued to not work when upload to Play Market(

After hard research... )

Solution:
SHA1 Fingerprint need get from "Google Play Console > Release Management > App Signing > App signing certificate"

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well. The error message isn't very informative. Your app needs to be whitelisted by the Google Pay team. You need to contact them at https://support.google.com/pay/merchants/contact/interest and provide the following:

- Issuer ID (this is on your merchant account page)
- App package name (this is found in your AndroidManifest.xml on the manifest parent element com.companyname.appname)
- SHA1 Fingerprint (This can be found by following the instructions outlined here: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/native-android-sdk)

So I finally got this to work, in the merchant center under the general area I changed the status field from DRAFT to UNDER_REVIEW. It immediately changed to approved and I could save the loyalty card.

[image: Status screenshot]

Comment: glad someone already posted here! any update on this? all documentations are updated, code samples are deprecated!

Comment: Hello, @Stevenr12 . Thank you for your answer. The app currentry isn't in white list (Discussion with google is in progress). Rest were done.

Comment: @LOG_TAG and Alex Nuts: See the edits, I got it working by updating the status in the merchant center.

Comment: @Stevenr12 *.setId(ISSUER_ID + "." + OFFER_OBJECT_ID)
            .setClassId(ISSUER_ID + "." + OFFER_CLASS_ID)*   can you clarifiy OFFER_OBJECT_ID and OFFER_CLASS_ID is same ? https://github.com/google-pay/s2gp-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/checkout/android/demo/MainActivity.java !  how do you creating layality Object ?

Comment: '.setClassId("2951238800106304306.OfferClassMonster3")
    .setId("2951238800106304306.OfferTestObject1")'  where we are getting OfferTestObject1 is a random number? just like primery key in DB ?

Comment: @LOG_TAG From the documentation: "The unique identifier for an object. This ID must be unique across all objects from an issuer. This value should follow the format issuer ID.identifier where the former is issued by Google and latter is chosen by you. The unique identifier should only include alphanumeric characters, '.', '_', or '-'." https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/reference/v1/loyaltyobject

In your code sample OfferTestObject1 will not be a unique value. Also, be careful about posting your issuer ID.